# Can't get value from text box, runtime error 424 object required

Tags: vba, ms-word, word-2010

I have a template with a text box control labeled `LName`.  There's also a button named `SaveTo` with the click script. Every time I try to get the text value from `Lname` using `Lname.text`  I get:

> "run-time error 424 Object required."

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub SaveTo_Click()

    ActiveDocument.SaveAs FileName:="c:\scripts\invoice\filex" & " " & Format(Date, "mm-dd-yy")

    MsgBox (Lname.Text)

End Sub
```

Comment: Is the form called `Lname` or is the textbox called `Lname`?

Comment: I would bet you need to define the form name or the text box name (whichever one is not called `Lname`)

Comment: The text box is LName and exists on the Word document.

Comment: If both `button` and `textbox` are on the same document then your code looks ok. Be sure it is placed in `Thisdocument module`

Comment: @KazJaw  That's what I thought but it won't run. I can't post a screen show here yet but what shows on the left in VBA is - TemplateProject Filex   - Microsoft Word Objects - ThisDocument  and my code on the right for the SaveTo button.

Answer (score -1):

Lname is probably already a string not an object.

try:

```
MsgBox (Lname)
```

It is helpful to have the "locals" window open when debugging VB so that you can watch the results as you debug

Comment: `Lname` is clearly an object per the original post.  Now it does make a difference if it is a textbox object or a form object but your method will not work.